# Como pegar valor selecionado no dropdownlist em Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como pegar o valor selecionado no `dropdownlist` ?
Preciso pegar o valor selecionado e passar esse valor para uma `session`.
Eu fiz com `textbox` desse jeito e funcionou, mas com `dropdownlist` não pega o valor.
Fiz o seguinte:

View

```
  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IRPJ) : 
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IRPJ, new SelectList(new List<Object> 
               {
                   new { value = 0, text = "1,5"},
                   new { value = 1, text = "4,8"}
               }, "value", "text", 0))
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Detalhes(FormCollection frm)
        {
             object irpj = frm[1].ToString().Replace(".",",");
             Session["IRPJ"] = irpj;

            return RedirectToAction("ImprimirBoleto", new
            {
                irpj = Session["IRPJ"].ToString(),
            });
```

Comment: nesse form, você só envia esse campo?

Comment: @RafaelCabral, Não, envio outros, coloquei só esse pq era o unico que eu preciso que eu não sabia, os outros são textbox e dessa forma funcionou.

Comment: então a solução do @RafaelMathias resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa do parâmetro FormCollection nesse caso.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Detalhes(string IRPJ)
    {

         Session["IRPJ"] = IRPJ.Replace(".",",");

        return RedirectToAction("ImprimirBoleto", new
        {
            irpj = Session["IRPJ"].ToString(),
        });
```

Comment: não vai man, passa 1 no parametro.

Comment: passa 1, porque é value dele, o value que vai pra view, coloque o valor que voce quer receber no "Value" que voce criou

Comment: @RafaelCabral Ahhh entendi, vou tentar.

Comment: @RafaelCabral, funcionou, Obrigado.